# Entity Framework 4.1: List of all of my class names

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4.1

Is there a way to get a list of all of my entity class names from EF?  I can use

```
ObjectContext.GetKnownProxyTypes()
```

-But this method only returns types that have been used in this current context.  I need all of the types that are in my DBContext.

DBContext.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
ObjectContext context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
EntityContainer container = context.MetadataWorkspace
   .GetEntityContainer(context.DefaultContainerName, DataSpace.CSpace);
string[] typeNames = container.BaseEntitySets
                              .OfType<EntitySet>()
                              .Select(es => es.ElementType.Name);
```

I'm not sure if adapter will correctly configure `DefaultContainerName`. It shoud probably be the same as your derived context class name.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use Reflection to get the list of Entity types from the DbContext?